# pandas dataframe find by column value with single quote?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

how to get row data from Dataframe using column value that has a single quote

```
hero_data = data.loc[data['Hero'] == "foo"] # work
hero_data = data.loc[data['Hero'] == "foo'd"] # not work
```

Comment: Try the back tick and see if it works . ` foo’d ` if it does not work u might have to escape the character with a backslash “foo\’d”

Comment: work on my side

Comment: oh damn, the problem coz in df are foo'D but i search using foo'd. thanks guys